# JSON поиск массива в масиве по элементу массива

Tags: javascript, массивы, json

что-то не могу сообразить. Получаю массив состоящий из массивов:
[image: Массив]

Внутри массива:
[image: Массив2]

Я понимаю что по индексу я могу получить доступ до вложенного массива, но это потоковые данные с сервера и расположение вложенных массивов меняется. Мне нужно получить **Вложенный массив по элементу 'AUDCAD_otc', в виде массива ['AUDCAD_otc', Array(1), 0.87942]**. Насколько понимаю нужно перебирать циклом все вложенные элементы массива, как это реализовать?

Comment: с помощью цикла.

Comment: Посмотрите методы массивов `filter` или `find`

Comment: Это понятно, что циклом перебираю все элементы массива, а вложенные массивы сравниваю с помощью filter или find. В коде, пожалуйста, реализацию.

Comment: В коде это вы сами. Тут помогают, а не решают за вас. Пробуйте и приходите с конкретной проблемой, что не получается.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, наверно я не корректно задал вопрос. И поэтому получаю негатив вместо помощи. Как решить мою проблему я знаю, меня не устраивает метод:

```js
var arr = [["#JNJ_otc",[[1,3]],182.603],["BTCGBP",[[1,4]],13870],["BTCUSD",[[1,4]],17034],["DOTUSD",[[1,2]],5.54],["EURGBP_otc",[[1,2]],0.86354],["EURJPY_otc",[[1,2]],138.174]];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i].includes("BTCUSD") == true){console.log(arr[i])};
}
```

Если вы знаете метод получения вложенного массива из массива по значению вложенного массива, прошу оставить свой метод в комментариях. Для меня важна скорость обработки данных, а не достал элемент, сравнил, достал следующий, сравнил и т.д.